# Multiple marker at this line message and phone type red symbol in spring tool suite

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am using spring MVC,hibernate in my project and come across the below symbol in Spring tool suite.
So can anybody explain what does it mean or this is something related to AOP concept of spring ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It marks places where one of AOP advice is activated. This often occur when you setup declarative transaction management -- methods annotated with `@Transactional` will have that icon.

Without the aid of such icon you might not be aware your code is doing something on the runtime